# Can't add markers to mobile google map

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile

Trying to create a PhoneGap mobile app.  Totally new to mobile apps, phonegap, and JS so bear with me.  This is where I'm at:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.710,-73.994), //New york, NY
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions)
};
```

With that, the map renders in the browser just fine.  When adding the following that I've found in a number of tutorials it refuses to render anything.  I am trying to do all of this in the googlemap/index.html page that I have created.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.710,-73.994), //New york, NY
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.710,-73.994)
    var marker = new.google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        title: "hello world!"
        });
    marker.setMap(map);
};
```

When I add the following, the entire page refuses to render.

Basically, I'm using the above method to display a google map, and I'm trying to add a pin to the center location.  Seems simple enough but proving to be beyond my abilities.

Comment: I have LogCat running (eclipse) and I can't find any logs logged when I spin up this page.  So I'm not sure where any rendering issues would be looged..??..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error on this line:

```
var marker = new.google.maps.Marker({
```

Notice that there is a dot between the `new` operator and the class name.

To fix, replace the line above with:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
```

Happy mapping!

PS: The error was reported in the (desktop) browser's console, I'm not sure how you'd see the same on an Android device.